# GUI Elements of Array Null After Button Click

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I believe the problem is somewhere in between a tick of my GameEngine. In other words, I think in one in-game buffer I believe the GUI elements are going null for some reason. Here is my code:
GameEngine class:

```
package pong;

import static pong.Main.window;

public class GameEngine{
    static GameState gameState;
    private long timeElapsed;
    
    public GameEngine(){
        gameState=new GameState(0);//0 is for the menu
    }
    
    public void run(){
        long beginTime=System.nanoTime();
        //33 million is 30 fps
        if(timeElapsed>=33333333){
            gameState.buffer();
            timeElapsed-=33333333;
        }
        window.getPanel().repaint();
        
        timeElapsed+=System.nanoTime()-beginTime;
    }
    
    public long getTimeElapsed(){
        return timeElapsed;
    }
}
```

GUIButton Class:

```
package pong;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import static pong.Panel.mouseClicked;
import static pong.Panel.mouseX;
import static pong.Panel.mouseY;

public abstract class GUIButton extends GUI{
    private boolean mouseOverButton,readyForButtonAction;
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        if(mouseOverButton){
            g.fillRect(x-5,y-5,110,40);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 30);
        }
        else{
            g.fillRect(x,y,100,30);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(x+5, y+5, 90, 20);
        }
    }
    
    @Override 
    public void buffer(){
        mouseOverButton=mouseX-8>x&&mouseX-8<x+100&&
            mouseY-32>y&&mouseY-32<y+30;
        if(mouseOverButton&&mouseClicked)
            readyForButtonAction=true;
    }
    
    public void buttonAction(){
        readyForButtonAction=false;
        mouseClicked=false;
    }
    
    public boolean buttonActionIsReady(){
        return readyForButtonAction;
    }
}
```

GUIButtonMultiplayer (The button that transfers you to the title GUI to the multiplayer options GUI)

```
package pong;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import static pong.GameState.GUI;

public class GUIButtonMultiPlayer extends GUIButton{

    public GUIButtonMultiPlayer(){
        x=300;
        y=300;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,12));
        g.drawString("Multiplayer",x+10,y+20);
    }
    @Override
    public void buttonAction() {
        super.buttonAction();
        GUI=new GUI[4];
        GUI[0]=new GUIButtonLocal();
        GUI[1]=new GUIButtonJoin();
        GUI[2]=new GUIButtonHost();
        GUI[3]=new GUIButtonBackMultiPlayer();
    }
}
```

Panel class (contains mouseClicked variable)

```
package pong;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import static pong.GameEngine.gameState;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements KeyListener,MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{
    static int mouseX,mouseY;
    static boolean mouseDown,mouseClicked;
    private boolean keyDown[];
    
    public Panel(){
        keyDown=new boolean[4];
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        gameState.paint((Graphics2D)g);
    }

    public boolean getKeyDown(int index){
        return keyDown[index];
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        switch(ke.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                keyDown[0]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                keyDown[1]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                keyDown[2]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                keyDown[3]=true;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        switch(ke.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                keyDown[0]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                keyDown[1]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                keyDown[2]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                keyDown[3]=false;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        mouseClicked=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        mouseDown=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        mouseDown=false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
        mouseX=me.getX();
        mouseY=me.getY();
    }
}
```

GameState class (implementation)

```
package pong;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import static pong.Panel.mouseClicked;

public class GameState{
    static GUI GUI[];
    private int ID;
    private Ball ball;
    private Paddle paddles[];
    
    public GameState(int id){
        ID=id;
        switch(ID){
            case 0://title screen
                GUI=new GUI[4];
                GUI[0]=new GUITitle();
                GUI[1]=new GUIButtonSinglePlayer();
                GUI[2]=new GUIButtonMultiPlayer();
                GUI[3]=new GUIButtonExit();
                break;
            case 1://single player
                paddles=new Paddle[2];
                //true indicates that it is a left paddle
                paddles[0]=new PaddlePlayer(true);
                paddles[1]=new PaddleCPU();
                GUI=new GUI[1];
                GUI[0]=new GUIScores();
                ball=new Ball(paddles,(GUIScores)GUI[0]);
                ((PaddleCPU)paddles[1]).setBall(ball);
                break;
            case 2://local multiplayer
                paddles=new Paddle[2];
                //true indicates that it is a left paddle
                paddles[0]=new PaddlePlayer(true);
                paddles[1]=new PaddlePlayer(false);
                GUI=new GUI[1];
                GUI[0]=new GUIScores();
                ball=new Ball(paddles,(GUIScores)GUI[0]);
                break;
            case 3://host multiplayer
                
                paddles=new Paddle[2];
                paddles[0]=new PaddleMultiplayer();
                paddles[1]=new PaddleMultiplayer();
                GUI=new GUI[1];
                GUI[0]=new GUIScores();
                ball=new Ball(paddles,(GUIScores)GUI[0]);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics2D g){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0,0,800,600);
        switch(ID){
            case 0://title screen
                    System.out.println();
                for(GUI gui:GUI){
                        System.out.println(gui==null);
                    gui.paint(g);
                }
                break;
            case 1:case 2:case 3://single player and multiplayer
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                for(int a=10;a<600;a+=20)
                    g.fillRect(380, a, 10, 10);
                ball.paint(g);
                for(Paddle paddle:paddles)
                    paddle.paint(g);
                GUI[0].paint(g);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    public void buffer(){
        switch(ID){
            case 0://title screen   
                for(GUI gui:GUI)
                    if(gui instanceof GUIButton && ((GUIButton)gui).buttonActionIsReady()){
                        ((GUIButton)gui).buttonAction();
                        break;
                    }
                    else gui.buffer();
                break;
            case 1:case 2:case 3://single player and multiplayer
                ball.buffer();
                for(Paddle paddle:paddles)
                    paddle.buffer();
                break;
        }
        mouseClicked=false;
    }
    
    public int getID(){
        return ID;
    }
}
```

This code generates a NullPointerException when the GUI is painted. If I comment out the line

```
gui.paint(g);
```

then it just creates a NullPointerException where the GUI is buffered instead. Here is a snippet of the output:

```
false
true
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

false
false
false
false
    at pong.GameState.paint(GameState.java:62)
    at pong.Panel.paintComponent(Panel.java:25)

false
false
false
false

false
false
false
false

false
false
false
false

false
false
false
false
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)

false
false
false
false

false
false
false
false

false
false
false
false

false
false
false
false
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)

false
false
false
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
false
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
```

Which GUI element shows up as null seems to be random.

Comment: Which line, in method `paint` of class `GameState`, is throwing `NullPointerException`? In other words which line is line 62 in file `GameState.java`?

Comment: gui.paint(g); right after the println

Comment: Are you sure that class member `GUI`, in class `GameState`, needs to be _static_? When you create an array, all the elements are null. It looks like you are creating an array but not setting a value for every element. And I strongly suggest that you adopt [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) because I think that will make your code easier for others to read and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems that you are using a static GameState.GUI array for you GUI elements (please correct me if I am wrong).

And elsewhere in code you are accessing this static GUI array sequentially. It seems that sometimes it happens that other code will change the contents of this static GUI array (code like this might be the culprit `GUI=new GUI[1];`), while other code is just about to start looping trough that array. You have to change you code so that this won't happen. You could synchronize the methods that are accessing this static GUI array (but that will block other methods and make them wait, which might or might not be okay for your use case).

If you identify that this is indeed the cause of the problem (it might not be), and you want to avoid using synchronized methods, you have some other options. You could look into how double buffering works. Using 2 arrays, always reading from the primary one and always modifying the secondary one, and just swapping between them.

Or, if you want to keep your current code, you could change these patterns:

```
GUI=new GUI[4];
GUI[0]=new GUITitle();
GUI[1]=new GUIButtonSinglePlayer();
GUI[2]=new GUIButtonMultiPlayer();
GUI[3]=new GUIButtonExit();
```

with this pattern everywhere in code where you use `GUI=new GUI[...];`:

```
GUI[] newGui=new GUI[4];
newGui[0]=new GUITitle();
newGui[1]=new GUIButtonSinglePlayer();
newGui[2]=new GUIButtonMultiPlayer();
newGui[3]=new GUIButtonExit();
GUI=newGui
```

This might be enough to avoid the problem.

Comment: I shouldn't have made GUI static. You were right. Making it a field member and using your code worked.